# How to decide on what priors distributions to use for parameters in PyMC3?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, pymc3, pymc

I am looking into PyMC3 package where I was interested in implementing the package in a scenario where I have several different signals and each signal has different amplitudes.

However, I am stuck on what type of priors I would need to use in order to implement PyMC3 into it and likelihood distribution to implement. Scenario example is shown in the following image:

[image: Signal plot]

I tried to implement it here, but, every time I keep on getting the error:

```
pymc3.exceptions.SamplingError: Bad initial energy
```

#### My Code

```
## Signal 1:
    with pm.Model() as model:
        # Parameters:
        # Prior Distributions:
        # BoundedNormal = pm.Bound(pm.Exponential, lower=0.0, upper=np.inf)
        # c = BoundedNormal('c', lam=10)
        # c = pm.Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=300)
        alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu = 0, sd = 10)
        beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu = 0, sd = 1)
        sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd = 1)
        mu = pm.Normal('mu', mu=0, sigma=1)
        sd = pm.HalfNormal('sd', sigma=1)

        # Observed data is from a Multinomial distribution:
        # Likelihood distributions:
        # bradford = pm.DensityDist('observed_data', logp=bradford_logp, observed=dict(value=S1, loc=mu, scale=sd, c=c))
        # observed_data = pm.Beta('observed_data', mu=mu, sd=sd, observed=S1)
        observed_data = pm.Beta('observed_data', alpha=alpha, beta=beta, mu=mu, sd=sd, observed=S1)

    with model:
        # obtain starting values via MAP
        startvals = pm.find_MAP(model=model)

        # instantiate sampler
        # step = pm.Metropolis()
        step = pm.HamiltonianMC()
        # step = pm.NUTS()

        # draw 5000 posterior samples
        trace = pm.sample(start=startvals, draws=1000, step=step, tune=500, chains=4, cores=1, discard_tuned_samples=True)

        # Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
        post_pred = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=500)
        print(post_pred['observed_data'].shape)

    plt.title('Trace Plot of Signal 1')
    pm.traceplot(trace, var_names=['mu', 'sd'], divergences=None, combined=True)
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
    plt.close('all')

    pm.plot_posterior(trace, var_names=['mu', 'sd'])
    plt.title('Posterior Plot of Signal 1')
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
    plt.close('all')
```

## Side questions

I also have been looking into the idea of implementing goodness to fitness test and Kalman filter while using different distributions other than Gaussian distribution, so, if you have the time I would appreciate it if can you have a look at them?. Both questions can be found here:

Goodness-to-fit tests link: [Goodness-to-fit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645648/how-to-create-a-search-for-common-fit-distribution-of-two-goodness-to-fit-tests)

Kalman filter link: [Kalman Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568133/how-to-implement-1d-kalman-filter-with-other-distribution)

---

## Edit 1

Say I have around 5 signals and would like to implement the Bayesian interface in order to see the difference in the PDF of the signals. How do I approach this problem? Do I need to create multiple models and get their posterior distribution? Like in this image:

[image: Distribution plots]

If I need to get the posterior distribution, Do I use the following code?

```
# Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
post_pred = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=500)
```

---

## Edit 2

If I have multiple signals can I implement it this way in order to see changes in `alpha` and `beta` in all signals?

```
        observed_data_S1 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S1', alpha=alpha[0], beta=beta[0], observed=S1[0])
        observed_data_S2 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S2', alpha=alpha[1], beta=beta[1], observed=S2[0])
        observed_data_S3 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S3', alpha=alpha[2], beta=beta[2], observed=S3[0])
        observed_data_S4 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S4', alpha=alpha[3], beta=beta[3], observed=S4[0])
        observed_data_S5 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S5', alpha=alpha[4], beta=beta[4], observed=S5[0])
        observed_data_S6 = pm.Beta('observed_data_S6', alpha=alpha[5], beta=beta[5], observed=S6[0])
```

**Edit 3:**

how can I plot multiple traces in one plot? because I am looking at multiple signals and thought of combing all alphas and betas together in one plot.

Comment: this error is a result of log_likelihood taking `np.inf` or `np.nan` values somewhere in between your model. can you please run model.get_test_vals()? This will give you the full report of log_prob values taken by each free tv in your model. Once you find which variable takes ``np.inf`` or ``np.nan`` values, you can traceback to remove or correct that rv's distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Mistake**: Beta distribution's parameters `alpha` and `beta` must be positive. You have used a Normal prior on them which allows that RV to take negative and 0 values. You can easily fix that by using `pm.Bound` on `pm.Normal` distribution or using `pm.HalfNormal` distribution instead.

**Second Mistake**: The other inconsistency is specifying `mu` and `sigma` along with `alpha` and `beta` parameters. Beta either accepts `mu` and `sigma` or `alpha` and `beta` but not both. The default behaviour is to use `alpha` and `beta` parameters over `mu` and `sigma` parameters. You are wasting a lot of computational power inferring `mu` and `sigma` out.

**Other Comments**: You should not use `sd` parameter in any distribution as of version 3.8 as it has been deprecated and will be removed in 3.9. Use `sigma` instead.

**Corrected Version**:

```py
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import pymc3 as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S1 = np.random.rand(10)

## Signal 1:
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Parameters:
    # Prior Distributions:
    # BoundedNormal = pm.Bound(pm.Exponential, lower=0.0, upper=np.inf)
    # c = BoundedNormal('c', lam=10)
    # c = pm.Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=300)
    alpha = pm.HalfNormal('alpha', sigma=10)
    beta = pm.HalfNormal('beta', sigma=1)

    # Observed data is from a Multinomial distribution:
    # Likelihood distributions:
    # bradford = pm.DensityDist('observed_data', logp=bradford_logp, observed=dict(value=S1, loc=mu, scale=sd, c=c))
    # observed_data = pm.Beta('observed_data', mu=mu, sd=sd, observed=S1)
    observed_data = pm.Beta('observed_data', alpha=alpha, beta=beta, observed=S1)

with model:
    # obtain starting values via MAP
    startvals = pm.find_MAP(model=model)

    # instantiate sampler
    # step = pm.Metropolis()
    step = pm.HamiltonianMC()
    # step = pm.NUTS()

    # draw 5000 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(start=startvals, draws=1000, step=step, tune=500, chains=4, cores=1, discard_tuned_samples=True)

    # Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
    post_pred = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, samples=500)
    print(post_pred['observed_data'].shape)

plt.title('Trace Plot of Signal 1')
pm.traceplot(trace, var_names=['alpha', 'beta'], divergences=None, combined=True)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
plt.close('all')

pm.plot_posterior(trace, var_names=['alpha', 'beta'])
plt.title('Posterior Plot of Signal 1')
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer with explanation, it seems to work and I have a question. It seems to run the samples based on the number of chains, however, it seems to take a while with each chain. Is there a way in order to decrease the time it takes to run each chain?

Comment: increase number of cores to sample in parallel. Do `trace = pm.sample(start=startvals, draws=1000, step=step, tune=500, chains=4, discard_tuned_samples=True)`. This will use all the cores by default

Comment: When I change the number of cores, it doesn't run the chains and the program just finishes the code.

Comment: I also have a question, say I have around 5 signals and would like to implement the bayesian interface in order to see the difference in the pdf of the signals. How do I approach this problem? Do I need to create multiple models and get their posterior distribution? Also, side question, Can I assume that bayesian interface behave similarly to the concept of the 1D Kalman filter where the bayesian interface can be called bayesian filter?

Comment: Which os are you using? I works on my Linux machine

Comment: I am using Windows and implementing the code in Pycharm

Comment: can you please report this on https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/new. You will get a better support there.

Comment: I will ask them about it. Also, did you have a look at my question in the last comment

Comment: I am not so comfortable with Kalman Filters so you may want to ask it there as well

Comment: Okay, what about this question: "say I have around 5 signals and would like to implement the bayesian interface in order to see the difference in the pdf of the signals. How do I approach this problem? Do I need to create multiple models and get their posterior distribution?"

Comment: I have provided a solution on the github issue tracker. Let's continue the discussion there.

Comment: While I agree the standard parameterization of a Beta is `alpha`, `beta`, the `mu`, `sd` one is usually more interpretable and can often sample more efficiently due to less correlation between the parameters.

Comment: @merv What I meant was either specify alpha, beta or mu, sigma. I agree that the mu, sigma parameterization is more interpretable but passing them along with alpha and beta  will lead to an inconsistent state. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Link to my question in Pymc3: https://discourse.pymc.io/t/how-to-decide-on-what-priors-distributions-to-use-for-parameters/5052/2